# VIM: Open separate help/hint/text file automatically in a vsplit

Tags: vim

I have the following problem, or lets say idea, with vim. When I am writing latex documents I want automatically open a file `~/.vim/latex_hints`, where I collected some hints, shortcuts, workarounds,..., in **vsplit** on the right side. The hint file should be loaded read only and automatically closing when I close the latex document.

After a few experiments I added the following commands to my vimrc:

```
function Handletexfile()
    setlocal cc=80
    setlocal wrap
    setlocal textwidth=80
    belowright vsplit +setl\ ro\ nomodifiable ~/.vim/latex_hints 
endfunction 

autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.tex  call Handletexfile()
```

and

```
function Handletexfileexit() 
    let tablist = []                                            
    call extend(tablist, tabpagebuflist(tabpagenr()))          
    for b in tablist 
            echo b . " ". bufname(b)
            if bufname(b) =~ "vim/.*_hints" 
                     echo "Close buffer..". b  
                     execute "bdelete! ".b
            endif 
    endfor 
endfunction 
autocmd BufWinLeave *.* call Handletexfileexit()
```

When I open a tex file, my hint file is displayed on the right side as read only and not modifiable. But when I close using `:q` or `:wq` the buffers open in the current tab are listed and the one matching to the hint file is selected by the `if` statement.  But I get the following output

```
1 abstract.tex
2 ~/.vim/latex_hints
Close buffer..2
```

and my vim crashes with an segfault.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your requirement translates pretty straightforward into Vimscript:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter <buffer> belowright vsplit +setl\ ro ~/.vim/latex_hints
```

Put this into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`, or prepend `:autocmd FileType tex` to the above command.

The latter part is more complex; on `BufWinLeave`, you'd have to check all other windows for the opened cheat file with `bufwinnr()`, go to it (`:wincmd w`), and `:close` it.

Comment: Ok, as you stated, this solves the first part of my problem. But I do not know how to handle the second part.

Comment: By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with (maybe as a separate question), we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you. The second part has some corner cases that need to be considered. If you come up with a solution on your own, you can handle those as you like. If I just post one solution, you're probably just going to return and complain to me.

Comment: The problem is that I am only a vim user and not a vim programmer. But I changed my post to the stuff I now found out which selects the right buffer but does not closes it correctly.

Comment: Ah, that's much better! I guess the crash is because you aren't supposed to delete buffers inside this autocmd. Instead `execute "bdelete! ".b`, try `call feedkeys(":bdelete! " . b . "\<CR>", 'n')`

Comment: This prevents the segfault, but on the first `:q` stroke the display stays the same but the focus moved in the hints window.

Comment: What version of Vim did the segfault occur? I can't seem to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative use the preview window with your hint file. The preview window gives you some advantages:

- It is small and out of the way
- Can close it easily via `<c-w>z` from any other window
- Can jump to the preview window from any window easily via `<c-w>P` (jump back via `<c-w>p`)

You can do this via the `:pedit` command. For example:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter <buffer> pedit +setl\ ro ~/.vim/latex_hints
```

Personally I feel like it would be better to create command or mapping to open your hints files as you may eventually out grow the file as time goes on. I would also set the `'bufhidden'` to `wipe` and un-list the buffer with `'nobuflisted'`.

You may also want to look into getting a nice [snippet plugin](http://vimawesome.com/?q=snippet).